# How to return an error message when denying the connection with django-channels?

Tags: django, django-channels

I've set up django-channels along with an endpoint to handle web socket connection, however, I'm stuck on the part of how to return an error message/error code when the connection is denied?
For example, if a user does not have the sufficient permissions, I don't want to accept the connection and want to return the reason of why is that.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`  you can use:

```
return await self.close(code=4000)
```

[WebSocket Close Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent/code)

[DjangoChannels Refrence](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/6af1bc3ab45f55e3f47d0d1d059d5db0a18a9581/channels/generic/websocket.py#L217)

Comment: But for this, wouldn't I first need to accept the connection and then close it? I'm trying to respond with a code without first accepting the connection, in cases of an invalid JWT token etc.

Comment: @FreelanceDev1 yes if you want to send him custom status_code in `connect` you should accept it first